# Unable to do calculation and get print out to label

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm doing the following code when they hit the calculate button in my app:

```
float sqft = ([textfield1.text floatValue]);
    float thick= ([textfield2.text floatValue]);
    float cos = ([textfield3.text floatValue]);
    float eff = ([textfield4.text floatValue]);

    float num = ((thick*.5)*sqft)/eff;
    float cost = (num*cos);
    float costft = (cost/sqft);

    label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.f",num];
    label2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.f",cost];
    label3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.f",costft];
```

When I do this the labels only return zeros.  I have set the labels to maually be strings just to see if it was a delegation thing but I can't figure out why my formulas return zeros only

Comment: Maybe you want `.2f`? Also, make sure `eff != 0.0f` and `sqft != 0.0f`. Also, `NSLog` the values or `num`, `cost`, and `costft` to make sure they are giving you the correct values.

Comment: Please post NSLog value of num, cost, costft.

Comment: @VenkatManoharPerepa, data type of sqft is:->float sqft = ([textfield1.text floatValue]);

Comment: What value in all text field ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the way you have used %2.f in your code,

%2.f gives you the rounded value of the answer in 2 number format. If any of your answer is less than or equals to 0.5 . then you get 0 as the answer.

**now it should work**

```
float sqft = ([textfield1.text floatValue]);
float thick= ([textfield2.text floatValue]);
float cos = ([textfield3.text floatValue]);
float eff = ([textfield4.text floatValue]);

float num = ((thick*.5)*sqft)/eff;
float cost = (num*cos);
float costft = (cost/sqft);

label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2f",num];
label2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2f",cost];
label3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2f",costft];
```

Comment: No, i'm getting value with this @"%2.f"

Answer (score 3):

Its working proper at my end . But in one case you will get `ZERO` value when your value is 0.786676 like that..

```
    textfield1.text = @"123.89";
    textfield2.text= @"123.00";
    textfield3.text= @"123.7";
    textfield4.text= @"123";


    float sqft = ([textfield1.text floatValue]);
    float thick= ([textfield2.text floatValue]);
    float cos = ([textfield3.text floatValue]);
    float eff = ([textfield4.text floatValue]);

    float num = ((thick*.5)*sqft)/eff;
    float cost = (num*cos);
    float costft = (cost/sqft);

    NSLog(@"Num : %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.f",num]);
    NSLog(@"Cost : %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.f",cost]);
    NSLog(@"Costft :  %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.f",costft]);
```

**Output**

**Num : 62
Cost : 7663
Costft :  62**

Answer (score 1):

You want to limit the digits after the decimal point to two -  that is why you are using `.2f`, right? If so, you should use this `@"%.2f"`

Just try this:

```
label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",num];  
label2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",cost];  
label3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",costft];
```